# SwipeRefreshLayout stop refreshing without animation

Tags: android, swiperefreshlayout

I'm aware that calling myRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false) will end the refresh animation... BUT, it doesn't just stop, it finishes it's current spin and animates off-screen.

Is there a way to avoid that in certain instances?  I'm looking to just have it instantly disappear.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this out:

```
 int cnt = swiperefresh.getChildCount();
                            for(int i=0; i<cnt; i++) {
                                View ch = swiperefresh.getChildAt(i);
                                if(ch.getClass().getSimpleName().equals("CircleImageView")) {
                                    ch.clearAnimation();
                                    ch.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                    swiperefresh.setRefreshing(false);
                                    ch.clearAnimation();
                                    break;
                                }
                            }
```

Answer (score 0):

I found an elegant way. There is a `reset()` method in `SwipeRefreshLayout` which cancels the animation and immediately hides the progress drawable without animation. Unfortunately this method is package private. But it is called during `setEnabled(false)`, so you could use it like this:

```
swipeRefreshLayout.setEnabled(false)
swipeRefreshLayout.setEnabled(true)
```